# Can you set up Android development inside a Virtual Machine?

Tags: android, eclipse

Last year I tried this on an AMD system running Windows 7.  I created a VMware VM, set up my Android development on it, but could not get the Android emulator to run because it did not have access to the actual graphics card.  I had to do away with the VM, and do the Android learning\development on the host system, so that the android Emulator had access to the graphics card.  That was about a year ago, and other things pulled me away.

I have a new system now, I7\Windows 8.  Have things changed in the past year, can I run an Android emulator (to test my programs), inside of a Virtual machine, or, do I need to use the host system again and forget the VM world?  I have seen some articles that say that you can install the Android OS itself in an x86 VM, I am not sure if that is the way to go.  The book that I am looking at now says that I need the JDK, JRE, Eclipse, SDK, etc., and says to install on Windows, can all that be set up on an android system?

Comment: Why would you want to develop Android inside a virtual machine?

Comment: @Donfuxx, Assuming you have enough space, virtual machines are great for versioning projects and versioning development environments. So let's say, you update the latest ADT plugin and the update breaks the build of your current project. With the snapshot of the VM last week, you can just roll back to that time last week when you had a working IDE and your project was building correctly. Or let's say you're teaching a class on Android programming, it can be a real pain to conduct a class when all your students are using different versions of a development environment.

Comment: I like to keep a clean desktop, too many software products, services, etc, clutter it up, slow it down, etc.  You try something, it may not work, and it might screw up your system. I want separate systems for developing on separate OS's (without having to purchase hardware). There is a quant old expression..."You don't s!*t in the kitchen".

Comment: Anectdotal info: I've been able to do that with a windows 7 guest on a windows 7 host (Virtual PC) and on a windows 8 host (Hyper-V).

Comment: You were able to run the Android emulators on the VM with no problems (the emulators had access to the graphics card of the host system)?  What is the hardware of the host system?

Comment: No, the emulators don't directly use the graphics card. The windows 8 host is a Surface Pro.

Comment: Let me ask it another way.  You developed Android apps on a VM, and tested using the emulator install on the VM, with no problems (on any emulated device)?.  Thanks.